# Как задать ограничение на запись в MySQL где значение в колонке из внешней таблицы != 2

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Есть две таблицы

**Categories**

```
Id | title | type_category
1  | Кат1  | 1
2  | Кат2  | 2
```

**Products**

```
id | title | category_id
```

Как запретить запись CATEGORY_ID в таблицу PRODUCTS если type_category != 2 ?

Сделать это нужно на уровне базы данных, может быть можно как то связать FOREIGN KEY и CHECK?
Или нужно использовать триггеры?

Comment: Trigger on before insert

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL 5 следует использовать триггер:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `products_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `products` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.category_id = 2 THEN
            SIGNAL sqlstate '45000';
        END IF;
  
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[SQLize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=23b9851448b4baf901a9fdf736cefe32)

В версии MySQL 8.0 и старше можно использовать `CONSTRAINT`:

```
create table `products` (
  id int,
  title varchar(255),
  category_id int,
  CONSTRAINT `category_id_not_2` CHECK (`category_id`<>2)
);
```

Рабочий пример [здесь](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a6e59c7a87ef25cf3b53310be1f5e610)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! Все очень понятно. Но вопрос немного в другом. Как запретить запись category_id если TYPE_CATEGORY != 2. Т.е. условие нужно связать как то с другой таблицей.